# How to integrate into visual studio 2015 build pipeline?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I am writing a VSIX extension for visual studio 2015 that subscribes to build events and performs additional verification asynchronously as follows:

```
class BuildEventController
{
    private readonly IThreadHandling _threading;
    private readonly BuildEvents _events;
    private readonly EnvDTE.DTE2 _dte2;

    public BuildEventController(...)
    {
        _dte2 = ... ;
        _threading = ... // instance of IThreadHandling
        _events = _dte2.Events.BuildEvents;
    }

    public override void Initialize()
    {
        _events.OnBuildProjConfigBegin += OnBuildProjectStarted;
    }

    private void OnBuildProjectStarted(...)
    {
        _threading.AsyncPump.RunAsync(async delegate
        {
            await TaskScheduler.Default;
            // do long-running work async
            // then... cancel the build if errors
            await _threading.AsyncPump.SwitchToMainThreadAsync();
            CancelBuild();
        });
    }

    private void CancelBuild()
    {
        _dte2.ExecuteCommand("Build.Cancel");
    }
}
```

The problem is that the actual build (compilation) may complete before my task will and I ultimately will lose the ability to cancel the build (even though I can still add errors to the errors tab).

Is there a way to schedule my work to be executed before or after the actual compilation so that it would be executed as a additional step in the build process?

Comment: What type of build validation do you want to do? Depending on your scenario, there's actually a number of different (and possibly better) places to hook up.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, this is technically not a build validation. It is additional verification of other project assets for validity/errors, think of bundles verifications, js validation via jslint, etc.

Comment: Also, which language or languages are you trying to target here?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski, let say JavaScript as an example. But it is not necessary a language, it can be just a set of configuration files for company-grown tool or framework that extension needs to verify.